# $http - null plain text response

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I have an $http POST call in AngularJS that won't show the server response if the request was bad.

```
myFactory.create = function(formData) {
  deferred = $q.defer()
  $http({method: 'POST', url: url, responseType: 'json', data: formData})
    .then(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    }, function(response, status, headers, config) {
      deferred.reject(response);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

When I submit incorrect data, the API responds with a 400 - Bad Request.  If I look at the response in Chrome Developer tools, there is a plain text message: "Vertical is not correct."  However, that message is not in the response on the $http error callback.

I can get everything else (status, headers and config) but my response data is null.

Successful POSTs are processed correctly so I know that the function generally works.

Any idea why I would be able to see the response in Chrome but not able to access it via $http?

Comment: suggestion: don't create promises where already exists promises. That is known as an anti pattern..

Comment: can you post the part where you actually get the data from the returned promise? Plus, i'm just assuming you change the 'url' to variable although it's doesn't exist. And you didn't declare deferred as a var.

Comment: Yes.  'url' is actually a variable and is generated elsewhere in my factory.  Right now, I have just been inspecting it with console.log(response) to see what is returned when there is an error.

Comment: How does your response look like?

Comment: {"data": null, "statusText": "Bad Request", "status": 400, "config": data...}.  

The "config" contains header information, the data originally submitted, headers, method, responseType, url, status, statusText, transformRequest and transformResponse.  Each of those has information below it but none of it contains the text that I can view under the "Response" tab in Developer Tools.

Comment: Because the responseType is set to json and based on what you said, it returns a plain string.

Comment: Here's the thing, the response from your server is not valid JSON, there might not be data at all. Either modify the server to return a proper JSON response describing the problem, or handle the situation by deriving from the status code or the status text and handle it. You might not need a full JSON response body

Comment: That is what I started to realize at the end of the day.  I'm going to see about changing the service to return JSON with the error.  Thank you for the help.  If you put that comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor to this:

```
myFactory.create = function(formData) {
  var url = 'api/create';  
  return $http({
    method: 'POST', 
    url: url, 
    responseType: 'json',  //Are you sure that it is returning a json??
    data: formData
  });
};
```

Then check the return of the promise like this wherever you wish to call it,

```
myFactory.create().then(
  function(data){
     console.dir(data);
  },function(response, status, headers, config) {
     console.dir(response);
  });
```

This should work and you should see the data on the logs.

Comment: If you are not sure about the answer and willing to be of help partially, it is better to use comments.

Comment: Sorry about that, but this answer is just way too long to comment and has a really high probability of being correct. Maybe some edits on how I said things will make it sound better.

Comment: I disagree, you are not changing the logic of the code aside from removing $q.defer() and returning the http promise directly, since the OP says the response data is null, this won't help. The only remaining case is that OP's server might not be returning valid JSON which you have mentioned, and that could be summed into a comment. I guess if that's the case, the question would be closed as a simple typographic error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow. I understand.

Comment: that's quite alright, we were all new to SO once :)